# Instantaneous center dilemma

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

During determination of instantaneous center and instantaneous axis of two non parallel velocity vectors we draw the respective perpendiculars and the point of intersection is the IC.

But, why do not we consider magnitude of velocity while determining the IC

[image]

Here, in the  picture bodies are identical. A and B are are at the same positions in both the bodies. Velocity of B is same in both cases whereas velocity of A differs.

So, if w be the angular velocity in case 1, it would be the same In case2 since B is at the same distance from IC and has same velocity in both cases.

But we see that w has to differ because vel of A is not the same In both cases?

So, is the theory of IC of non parallel vectors Incorrect ?
Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

You should draw the perpendicular from the midpoint of the vector, not the end. This takes into account the magnitudes of the velocities.

Comment: But, why should it be done in that way? It has not been mentioned in the books I follow or any site I searched including Wikipedia.